# How to use SQL parameters with IF conditions and what datatype is equal to the NVARCHAR. OLeDB, VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, parameters, sql-injection

So my question actually has more than 2 parts but all linked with protecting my application against SQL injection.

Lately I am rebuilding my application to make it SQL injection proof. My application is written in VB.NET and I am using `Parameters.Add` to protect the queries.

**UPDATE first question:**

Found out that the `NVARCHAR` datatype is equal to the `WChar` datatype in OLEDB. When hovering over `WChar` it says in the description it is `WSTR`.

I am having a few questions though of which I cant find the answer on the web.
The first one, and I guess the easiest one is what the datatype in OleDB is of the NVARCHAR. When doing some research I found this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130984.aspx which states that in OleDB the `DBTYPE_WSTR` datatype is the same as the `NVARCHAR` (which I am using in my t-SQL server). However when adding parameters in my VB application there is no such datatype available (`WSTR`). Some options are the `VarChar`, `VarWChar`, `WChar`, `LongVarChar`, `LongVarWChar`.

The question is, which one is the right one? I assume it is `VarChar`.

**-------UPDATED UNTIL HERE-----**

The second question is about how to handle parameters when a IF condition is involved in the query (see the example below).

```
sSQL1 = "SELECT [Omschrijving], [Nummer], [OrderType], [Orderdatum] FROM [Orders] WHERE [OrderDatum]>dateadd(""ww"",-4,GetDate()) "
        If sOrderType <> "" Then    
            sSQL1 &= "AND ([OrderType]=""" & sOrderType & """)"

        End If
        sSQL1 &= "ORDER BY [Orders].[Nummer] DESC;"

        lstOrder.Items.Clear()
        Try
            OpenConn()
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL1, cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            While dr.Read()
                lstOrder.Items.Add(dr("nummer") & " - " & dr("Omschrijving"))
            End While

        Catch
            Debug.Print(sSQL1)
            MsgBox("Error: " & sSQL1)
        End Try

        dr.Close()
        CloseConn()
```

How should I rewrite this with using parameters? Do I need to instantiate the `cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL1, cn)` in the if condition together with the `Parameters.Add` ? But I guess this would also mean I have to open the connection earlier?

I thought about rewriting in something like this:

```
OpenConn()

        sSQL1 = "SELECT [Omschrijving], [Nummer], [OrderType], [Orderdatum] FROM [Orders] WHERE [OrderDatum]>dateadd(""ww"",-4,GetDate()) "
        If sOrderType <> "" Then    
            sSQL1 &= "AND ([OrderType]=?)"

            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL1, cn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderType", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = sOrderType
        Else
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL1, cn)
        End If
        sSQL1 &= "ORDER BY [Orders].[Nummer] DESC;"

        lstOrder.Items.Clear()
        Try

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            While dr.Read()
                lstOrder.Items.Add(dr("nummer") & " - " & dr("Omschrijving"))
            End While

        Catch
            Debug.Print(sSQL1)
            MsgBox("Error: " & sSQL1)
        End Try
```

No idea if this works though (and for now I sadly can't test it).

Another question is: Do I need to use parameters for the `dateadd` (see query above) in the query as well? And if I do, how?

The last question is, when I am using the `Parameters.Add`, is it best to give a `size` value as well or is this not necessary?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to your first question that
I think this is the list of equal data-types you want:

```
SQL Server | OLEDB (ADO => ad+...)
-----------+---------------
char       | Char 
nchar      | WChar
varchar    | VarChar
nvarchar   | VarWChar
text       | LongVarChar
ntext      | LongWVarChar
```